# How to create effective forest models(RF-PCT) using Clus

Tags: weka, arff, multilabel-classification

I try to use Clus and my training data to create a **Random Forest-Predictive Clustering Tree** model. Why it always return me a **0 model** no mater which training set I use?

The model is constructed using [Clus](http://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/clus/)

**Here are the result model:**

## Default Model

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] [77037.0,74642.0,72382.0,75705.0,78171.0,59793.0,78443.0,75270.0,80386.0,75289.0,80333.0,77827.0,72847.0,79762.0,77135.0,58949.0,80452.0,51354.0,72968.0,69297.0,78558.0,78889.0,75170.0,80212.0,77237.0,80300.0,79275.0,79068.0]: 80653
```

## Original Model

Forest with 0 models

**Here are parts of my data:**

```
@attribute Sci-Fi {0,1}
@attribute Crime {0,1}
@attribute Romance {0,1}
@attribute Animation {0,1}
@attribute Music {0,1}
@attribute Comedy {0,1}
@attribute War {0,1}
@attribute Horror {0,1}
@attribute Film-Noir {0,1}
@attribute Adventure {0,1}
@attribute News {0,1}
@attribute Western {0,1}
@attribute Thriller {0,1}
@attribute Adult {0,1}
@attribute Mystery {0,1}
@attribute Short {0,1}
@attribute Talk-Show {0,1}
@attribute Drama {0,1}
@attribute Action {0,1}
@attribute Documentary {0,1}
@attribute Musical {0,1}
@attribute History {0,1}
@attribute Family {0,1}
@attribute Reality-TV {0,1}
@attribute Fantasy {0,1}
@attribute Game-Show {0,1}
@attribute Sport {0,1}
@attribute Biography {0,1}
@attribute V1 numeric
@attribute V2 numeric
@attribute V3 numeric
@attribute V4 numeric
@attribute V5 numeric
...
@attribute V501 numeric

 @data
0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,14,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,5,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,27,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,2,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,7,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: Can you show us the settings file?